# How to remove white space product image on product detail page magento 2.3?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I have getting issue of white space on product detail page.

I tried to fixed using view.xml but no success.

[image]

I have added image to show where I am getting white space.

Comment: Getting error: > etc/view.xml" is invalid: Element 'frame': This element is not
> expected. Expected is ( background ). Line: 59 Verify the XML and try
> again.

Comment: not getting any kind of error I have already checked it.

Answer (score 2):

In your **view.xml** set "width" and "height" as you wish and then "transparency" , "aspect_ratio" and "frame" to "false"

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<view xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/view.xsd">
    <media>
        <images module="Magento_Catalog">
            <image id="category_page_list" type="small_image">
                <width>240</width>
                <height>300</height>
                <transparency>false</transparency>
                <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
            </image>
        </images>
    </media>
</view>
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution but no luck.

Comment: Run all commands upgrade,indexing,caching,deploy

Comment: I have already done that all and but the thing is I want to remove that white space from product detail page not from product listing page.

Comment: You can use the below code. It worked for me on magento 2.2.11

<image id="product_page_image_large" type="image">
                <transparency>false</transparency>
                <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
                <frame>false</frame>
</image>

Answer (score 0):

its working on product list and Detail Page
i have used

```
 <transparency>false</transparency>
 <aspect_ratio>false</aspect_ratio>
 <frame>false</frame>
```

[image: this is before image]
this is before image

[image: this is after image]
this is after image